# Not able to record in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter 2.13 am not able to start recording , am getting error not allowing me to record through Jmeter.

**ERROR**: *Could not create script recorder -see log for details
Illegal option: -ext
Try keytool -help
'keytool -genkeypair -alias: root_ca: -dname "CN=_DO_NOT_INSTALL unless this is your certificate (JMeter root CA), OU=Username: , C=US" -keyalg RSA -keystore proxyserer.jks ..........*

Please tell me how to resolve this error

***Thanks in advance***

[Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEhea.png)

Comment: can you please share your Test Script Recorder settings? is the error populated when you click on Start button in the recorder? share the jmeter.log error info. Does you place certificates in Jmeter directory in order to support https website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upgrade to [JDK 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) or higher to get rid of this error.

I would also recommend considering upgrading to the latest JMeter version (currently it is [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31)) as newer JMeter versions contain not only new features, but a lot of performance improvements and bug fixes.